# Functional equation with function defined on $\mathbb{N}^{*}$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Let $ f:\mathbb{N}^{*} \mapsto \mathbb{N}^{*} $ be a function with the following property: $$ \frac{f(x+1)f(x)-2x}{f(x)}=\frac{2f^2(x)}{x+f(x)}-1$$
Determine all functions with this property.
(I'm sure the only function is $f(x)=x$).

Comment: What is $\Bbb{N}^*$?

Comment: The set of positive integers!

Comment: @TommyT. In general, we just denote the set of positive integers by $\Bbb N$, do you mean by $\Bbb N^*$ the following? $\Bbb N-\{0\}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=1$ and multiply both sides by $f(1)$ to determine that $\displaystyle \frac{2f^3(1)}{1+f(1)}$ is an integer since all other terms are integers.  Since $1+f(1)$ and $f(1)$ are relatively prime, it follows that $(1+f(1))|2$, and since $f(1)$ is positive, $f(1) = 1$.

By induction all values of $f$ are determined by the value of $f(1)$ (just solve for $f(x+1)$ in terms of $f(x)$) so there is at most one such function.  Since $f(x) = x$ works, it is the only such function.

Comment: At the end, by induction all values...How with induction? :-)

Comment: Certainly $f(1)$ is determined by $f(1)$.  One can solve for $f(x+1)$ in terms of $f(x)$.  Hence $f(n+1)$ is determined by $f(n)$ for any $n\geq 1$, and by the induction hypothesis $f(n)$ is determined by $f(1)$, so $f(n+1)$ is determined by $f(1)$.

Comment: Nice! That's a nice idea!